# Query using string from custom field as array value

Tags: wp-query, custom-field, array

Firstly, what I am trying to do is display posts from Category x on posts from Category y where text from a custom field on post from Cat y matches text from one of 2 custom fields on cat x.

I am using Advanced Custom Fields and have a custom text field on each post from cat x and y to store a list of attributes. e.g. red,car,sports,alloys.

I then want to check to see if they match up between posts and pull in the post where they do.

The trouble I am having is getting the custom field value (text field) and then passing it into the array) The text field contains comma seperated values e.g. "car", "red" if I print the field it shows this. I have tried converting the string to an array using explode, but still it is returning nothig. If I manually add "car", "red" to the array, it works.

I am currently using WP_Query, my latest query is:

```
    <?php 

$list = get_field( "main_attributes" );

$arr = array($list);

$array = explode(',', $list);

$args = array(
    'meta_query' => array(
        'relation' => 'OR',
        array(
            'key'     => 'style_atrributes',
            'value'   => $array,
            'compare' => 'IN'
        ),
        array(
            'key'     => 'car_atrributes',
            'value'   => '$array',
            'compare' => 'IN'
        ),
    ),
);



$custom_query = new WP_Query($args); 
while($custom_query->have_posts()) : $custom_query->the_post(); ?>

    <div <?php post_class(); ?> id="post-<?php the_ID(); ?>">
        <h1><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></h1>
        <?php the_content(); ?>
    </div>

<?php endwhile; ?>
<?php wp_reset_postdata(); // reset the query ?>
```

Comment: hmmm... you ***are*** using text as part of an array? Where are you storing the "red" and "car" data and how are you retrieving it. You haven't posted enough code.

Comment: I am storing "red" and "car' etc as text in a custom field on each post page. This is the full block of code I have place in the single.php see above.

Comment: The fact that it is returning all the pages makes me think it is working, but the query is wrong. Could it be returning false positives? I want it to check the fill word before comma, e.g. red, green, but would it return both because they both include letter 'e' Sorry my php is weak!

Comment: If I change compare to 'compare' => 'LIKE' and type the array as 'value'   =>  array("red", "car") it works. But if I change the array to the field its doesnt. Even thought if I print the field out it is exactly the same. "red", "car"

Comment: sorry meant if I change 'LIKE' to 'IN'

Comment: But the only meta value you are searching for is 'main_atrributes'-- literally, "main_atrributes". Where does "red", or "car", or anything else come into play?

Comment: Oh yeah I see what you are saying, that is the name of the custom field, but I see why that probably wouldn't work. I also tried adding this: $list = get_field( "main_attributes" ); and changing value to: 'value'   => array( $list ) But to no luck. I do print_r($list); it prints the attribute list correctly..

Comment: I've tried converting the string into an array also using explode, but again it is printing out the array, but not working when I try and drop it in as a value.

Comment: `get_field()` is not a WordPress function.

Comment: It works to return the value of a custom field using advanced custom fields: http://www.advancedcustomfields.com/resources/get_field/

Comment: I know it is ACF. I just didn't know if you had that installed.

Comment: Ah right yeah I'm using acf, any thoughts? Seems I'm converting the string to an array incorrectly? Or is this not going to be possible?

Comment: Edit the question to include more of the information in the comments and update the block of case please

Comment: I have got it working with the above code, just saved the custom fields without quotes. Thanks for you time/help :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay anyone wanting to achieve this, the code works. Just save the values in the custom field without quotes. e.g. red, car

```
    <?php 

$list = get_field( "main_attributes" );


$array = explode(',', $list);

$args = array(
    'meta_query' => array(
        'relation' => 'OR',
        array(
            'key'     => 'style_atrributes',
            'value'   => $array,
            'compare' => 'IN'
        ),
        array(
            'key'     => 'car_atrributes',
            'value'   => $array,
            'compare' => 'IN'
        ),
    ),
);



$custom_query = new WP_Query($args); 
while($custom_query->have_posts()) : $custom_query->the_post(); ?>

    <div <?php post_class(); ?> id="post-<?php the_ID(); ?>">
        <h1><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></h1>
        <?php the_content(); ?>
    </div>

<?php endwhile; ?>
<?php wp_reset_postdata(); // reset the query ?>
```

Comment: I upvoted. Solving your own question usually deserves that IMHO. Doesn't `get_field()` return an array already though?

Comment: Thanks for the upvote. I actually realised this doesn't do what a want either. in my test data I only had one value in 'car_attributes' e.g. 'car' so it worked. But if I add another so: car, red it searches for the exact match and doesnt find it. I guess what I am trying to do is pick out matches from two arrays.. currently looking to see how this is possilble